# Excel VBA Deleting Rows Out of Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code which is creating two separate reports, on two separate tabs.  The first report generated by the code works fine, and produces the desired output.  The second report, however, does not.  The first report uses this code:

```
'Find the last row of the table
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Autofit all columns
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Filter then delete all rows that don't have a client
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$P" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$256").AutoFilter Field:=3 'unfilter this column
```

The second report (on a different tab) uses the below code, which somehow deletes row 1 (column header), and which thereby causes downstream impacts.

```
'Find the last row of the table
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Autofit all columns
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'Filter then delete all rows that don't have a client
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$P" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$256").AutoFilter Field:=3 'unfilter this column
```

Seemingly, this is the same code, but it's producing different behaviors.  Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure it *deletes* the row? Or does it perhaps filter it out?  Also, perhaps it's the use of `$A$1`? What if you change that to `$A$2`?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me - are you sure your column headers on the second tab are on row 1?

Comment: Couple questions there, so I'll answer in order.  Yes, it deletes row 1.  It works if I change this to `$A$2`:   `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="`    but that doesn't explain why the first code works, and the second one doesn't.  Finally, yes I am sure the column headers are in row 1.  Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Second update: As I step through the new code containing `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$P" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="` it is _still_ deleting the first (header) row.  Oddly, it did not do this the first time I ran the code with that update.

Comment: This will happen when `lastRow = 1`

Comment: I added `MsgBox (lastRow)` to the code, and the message box returned "1045874", so I don't think this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be presenting itself based on where your macros are running from in relation to where you are actively in the workbook.  Try to qualify your objects.

```
LastRow = Sheets("YOUR SHEET NAME").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("YOUR SHEET NAME").Cells.Select
Sheets("YOUR SHEET NAME").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Hope this helps.

The second code is filtering by column 3.  Are you sure cell C1 is not "="?